# HTTP GET gives 400 bad request (telnet, arduino)

Tags: http, arduino, telnet, bad-request

For a school project I'm building a small Arduino based weather station. This station sends its data to a PHP page (using a CC3000) which puts it into a MySQL database. The code I have worked a few days ago and somehow stopped working now.
the problem is that I get a 400 bad request back from my server. The code I use is as follows

```
while (!client.connected()){
    Connect();
  }
  client.fastrprint(F(" GET "));
  client.fastrprint(PAGE);
  client.fastrprint(F("?sensor="));
  client.fastrprint(sensor);
  client.fastrprint(F("&&unit="));
  client.fastrprint(unit);
  client.fastrprint(F("&&value="));
  client.fastrprint(charBuffer);
  client.fastrprint(F("&&pass="));
  client.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
  client.fastrprint(F("Host: ")); 
  client.fastrprint(SERVER); 
  client.fastrprint(F(":80\r\n"));
  client.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
  client.println();
```

Now most of that code comes from sample functions of adafruit. The strange thing is that when I use telnet to send the same request I also get a HTTP 400 bad request back. But when I request the URL using a browser the PHP page accepts the data and puts it into my database.
here is the command I used in telnet.

```
GET /weer/add.php?sensor=DHT&&unit=C&&value=99.99&&pass= HTTP:/1.1
Host:www.---.nl
```

Can anyone help me figuring out what's wrong with my request?

The server runs nginx 1.7.0 if that helps

Comment: What did you change from a few days ago? Why double ampersands? What does the request look like in Nginx' access log? There's a difference in the code - you're suffixing `:80` to the host name. `PAGE`, `SERVER` are what?

Comment: the thing is that I had a few days of and didn't change anything.
PAGE is /weer/add.php and SERVER is the adress of the website so www.sitename.nl
I added that :80 today because someone here recommended to do so. It shouldn't make a difference.
I'm sorry but i don't have acces to the acces log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I changed a the code so that it uses a buffer of the format string to compile the string. this buffer is then send using client.println. in the end I'm still sending the exact same message to my server, but now it works. I'm guessing the client.fastrprint screws things up.

```
String buffer = "GET ";
  buffer += PAGE;
  buffer += "?sensor=";
  buffer += sensor;
  buffer += "&&unit=";
  buffer += unit;
  buffer += "&&value=";
  buffer += charBuffer;
  buffer += "&&pass=";
  buffer += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  buffer += "Host: ";
  buffer += SERVER;
  buffer += ":80\r\n\r\n";

  while (!client.connected()){
    Connect();
  }
  client.println(buffer);
```